# Can powershell be used as web-programming?

Tags: powershell, web, webserver

I come  from linux background and noticed that windows has its own scripting language called powershell. Can Powershell be used for doing webprogramming like CGI/Perl/Python in Linux with Apache or any webserver?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but I really do not see a point for that. Powershell is a general-purpose automation tool. Though it can be used to create dynamic web content, it doesn't mean it is good an idea.

Usually in Windows environments one is way better off either sticking with Asp.Net for pure Microsoft ecosystems. For mixed stack, one should consider using same tools as with Linux. That is, PHP, Ruby/Rails and whatnot are available on Windows too.

Comment: Agreed, but if you are interested in pursuing Powershell for web development, take a look at Powershell Pipeworks framework from James Brundage http://powershellpipeworks.com/

Comment: Agreed that PowerShell isn't necessary for web development but your statement about ASP.NET being only for pure Microsoft ecosystems is terribly wrong.  Just as with PHP, ASP renders the code down to raw HTML so any browser platform can read the web page, also disregarding OS platform since browser is all server-side scripting languages care about.

Comment: @thepip3r You've misunderstood the "pure Microsoft ecosystem" part. It means that the server side is running only MS products. In such an environment, Asp.Net is quite obvious a choice.

Comment: @vonPryz, you're right.  I did misunderstand the breadth of your meaning of the Windows ecosystem.  And while Asp.NET proabably is the obvious choice in most Microsoft environments, I have seen Apache/PHP/MySQL used on Windows systems.  Thanks for the clarification and sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

I full agree with @VonPryz (+1).

But, just in order to answer your question more accuratly, you can have a look at this open source product [PowerShell Web Server](http://www.poshserver.net/) or this commercial one [Create Dynamic Web Content With PowerShel](http://www.powershellserver.com/overview/web/)l